# Unable to insert string with comma in MySql DB

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have DB with table at MySQL. I m trying to insert string which have multiple commas like London,India,Japan against one column.

I tried to encode string using URLEncoder.encode(London,India,Japan,"UTF-8") before passing to insert command but it did not work. Though the outcome of encoder was London+%2C+India+%2C+Japan.

If I remove the commnas and use other symbol like underscore or semicolon, insertion is working fine.

Can someone guide. how can I pass this string. I searched a lot few suggest to replace comma with ,/ but even that did not work.

I m using PHP as below:

```
<?php
require_once("../dbconnect.php"); 

if(!$_REQUEST['table'] || !$_REQUEST['columns'] || !$_REQUEST['values']){
    echo "No data found.";
    exit;
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['table'])) {
    $table= trim($_REQUEST['table']);

}
if(isset($_REQUEST['columns'])){
    $columns =   trim($_REQUEST['columns']);

} 
if(isset($_REQUEST['values'])){
    $values =   trim($_REQUEST['values']);

    $new_values  = explode(',',addslashes($values));
    $values = join("','",$new_values);
}

$query = "INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES('$values')";
//echo $query;
    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
   $Id =    mysqli_insert_id($conn);
if (!$Id) {    
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();

} else{
    echo "$Id";
}
exit;
?>
```

and calling it using below url to insert data
insertData.php?table=tdata&columns=places,amount&values=URLEncoder.encode("London,India,Japan","UTF-8")+","+500;

Column datatype is Text and length is blank

I got below Error when I hit URL:

Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB:

Comment: update your question add  add your code  ..

Comment: which error you get and what is your code?

Comment: Are you sending the string enclosed within quotes (something like `'London,India,Japan'`)?

Comment: Also, what is the size of the column you are attempting to insert your text into?

Comment: pls see updated code for all your queries

Comment: just print the `$query` after you create it to see what's wrong with it. You have problems with quotes I'm sure

Comment: Query is results as INSERT INTO tdata(places,amount)VALUES('London','India','Japan',500) so basically entire string split into 4 difference column inputs

Comment: Similar to @VladyslavMatviienko, in your error message change $sql to $query.

Comment: @Andy Here is Query outcome INSERT INTO tdata(places,amount)VALUES('London','India','Japan',500)

Comment: Seems like the number of values doesn't match number of columns.  And post the query outcome in post - so it's easier for everyone to see.